# Beamer cambridgeUS section and subsection not enough space

Tags: beamer, fontsize, section-titles, frame-title, subsection

I'm writing a latex Beamer file, and I got some problems when setting the section & subsection. The space is not enough to display my text. I want to increase the scope to include the text, rather than reduce the text size.

[image]

here is my text

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\section{Title Page}
\subsection{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\begin{frame}
\title{Estimation}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick hack, you could use `\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}}{}`

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Title Page}
\subsection{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\begin{frame}
\title{Estimation}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need more fine control over the size, you can change the height of the headline by modifying the value in `ht=...` (and possibly `dp=...`) in the following redefinition of the headline:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=4.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=4.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Title Page}
\subsection{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\begin{frame}
\title{Estimation}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]